# How can i link a whole column in wordpress using css?

Tags: wordpress

`AM kasingye Viva Junior Web developer, am facing a problem when i want to make the whole column in wordpress clickable as a link``

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole column you want to link in an `a` tag.

If you are using `Elementor pro` then you can apply **the link via `CSS`** through Advance Tab

If you are using `Gutenberg` then you can apply **the link via `CSS`** through `Advance Tab` by installing another plugin named `Spectra - WordPress Gutenberg Blocks`.

`Spectra - WordPress Gutenberg Blocks:`
Power up the Gutenberg editor with advanced and powerful blocks that help you build websites in no time! This first Gutenberg plugin is here to make website building an ultimate journey.

[Check out this plugin from the WordPress directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg/)

**May Be you ask: Where to place `CSS`?**
Here is the simple answer to this:

For Elementor, you can define CSS styles in Custom CSS at the end of the Advance Tab

For Gutenberg, You can add styles in the related CSS file or in the Custom CSS section in the Admin or Customization Panel.

I hope It'll help you!

Comment: Hi, could you please add the code? [How to give a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)